# Warning LNK4098 and LNK1123 when working with OpenGL in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, compiler-errors

So I'm trying to get the first exercise in the OpenGL Superbible 5th edition to run. It should draw a triangle. I've managed to fix all of my dumb typos. Now I'm down to just two error messages, one of which I think is familiar;

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use              /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

I think I stumbled across LNK1123 when I first used C++, and I fixed it by disabling 'Incremental Linking' in the project settings. However, when I try this now, though the program does run and a window does open, no triangle is drawn, and I'm given a list of errors relating to OpenGL tools. And LNK4098 is still there as well.

This is my first project using library imports. Although it was a minefield trying to get it to work, I finally got the graphics libraries GLEW and freeGLUT into my project, by adding them to the project's include path list, and then adding them as existing items to the project. But I suspect that this method has upset the mighty VC++. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with OpenGL. This error is basically telling you that you are using the multi-threaded version of Microsoft's C standard library in a project that is already linking to another version of the library.

The interesting thing is that newer versions of MSVC do not have different versions of the C standard library for threaded vs. non-threaded. Thus, your MSVC version is relevant information that is absent from the question.

In any case, the linker warning actually tells you exactly how to resolve the warning. You can add `/NODEFAULTLIB:libc` to the linker command in your project settings. There is usually an edit-box in the project settings to accomplish this as well, but since its location varies from version to version, adding this to the command-line is simpler.

---

As for the COFF issue, this is related to the generation of debug symbols in an incremental linking project. `/INCREMENTAL:NO` should fix this issue. Regarding the cause of it, have you installed different versions of MSVC on this system in the past?